# ContentResolver query functions blocks

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use a content resolver to get data from a content provider. I'm trying to do this in a thread and continuously query for new data (every 5 seconds or so).

```
public void run()
{
  while (!this.cancelled)
  {
    // get the cursor to all the msgs
    Cursor cur = this.mContentResolver.query(MY_URI, null, null, null, null);

    .... // iterate through cursor, store some data, etc. (quick process)

    // sleep the thread for a bit before we query again
    try
    {
      Thread.sleep(5000); // sleep for 5 seconds
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

(The run method is part of my Thread that I have launched from my main UI Thread).

The first time the query executes, it doesn't appear to block for any significant amount of time (maybe a few ms), which seems to me like a normal operation. Every subsequent time query is called, it blocks for EXACTLY 30 seconds.

I have no idea why it would execute immediately the first time, then block for 30 seconds every subsequent time.

Can anyone shed some light as to why I maybe seeing this behaviour?

Thanks

EDIT: Found the reason, the Content provider was waiting for 30 seconds to clean up the cursor before releasing a new one.

Comment: You should definitely implement the "sleeping" by using [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) instead of looping indefinitely and calling Thread.sleep(). Thread.sleep() is very, *very* ugly and usually just gets you in trouble..

Comment: First, try using another URI. If problems stays, it might be issue in your code, if problems goes away then this is specific behavior of that specific content provider.

Comment: Use content observers; don't poll for changes

Comment: I'll look into content observers. Do you have a link to a good tutorial on how to use content observers?

Comment: content providers must be responsive.  I presume that internally there is a binder which must be established.  What is the delay associated with establishing that binder?